# Error: when i tried to run running project with 2.2 then it gives error

Tags: android

I build and run my project with 1.5 SDK
But when I tried to run my project after installing 2.2. I get this error.
Please help; what does this Error mean ? And how do I solve it ?

```
W/ResourceType( 2680): Bad string block: string #8 extends to 1575, past end at 60
W/ResourceType( 2680): Bad string block: string #7 extends to 2075, past end at 60
W/ResourceType( 2680): Bad string block: string #6 extends to 1303, past end at 60
W/ResourceType( 2680): Bad string block: string #5 extends to 1299, past end at 60
W/ResourceType( 2680): Bad string block: string #4 extends to 1295, past end at 60
W/ResourceType( 2680): Bad string block: string #3 extends to 1553, past end at 60
W/ResourceType( 2680): Bad string block: string #2 extends to 1292, past end at 60
W/ResourceType( 2680): Bad string block: string #1 extends to 516, past end at 60
W/ResourceType( 2680): Bad string block: string #0 extends to 1029, past end at 60
res\layout\chart.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'id' in package 'android'
res\layout\chart.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_width' in package 'android'
res\layout\chart.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_height' in package 'android'
res\layout\chart.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'orientation' in package 'android'
res\layout\chart.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'id' in package 'android'
res\layout\chart.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_width' in package 'android'
res\layout\chart.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_height' in package 'android'
res\layout\chart.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'text' in package 'android'
```

Comment: please post the content of `chart.xml` (I guess you forgot the prefix `android:`)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using NetBeans, which uses the aapt from 2.1 with the JAR from 2.2.

Edit

~/.netbean/6.9/build.properties

and look for "aapt" in a line similar to this:

> platforms.Android_2.2___Google_APIs.aapt=/opt/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-2.1/tools/aapt

Then replace "android-2.1" with "android-8" and you should be done.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.